# Map mongo aggregation result to array

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a mongo query that looks like this:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([ { 
    $group: { 
        _id: null,
        price: {
            $sum: "$price"
        },
        inventory: {
            $sum: "$inventory"
        }
    }
}])
```

Which returns

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "price" : 26,
    "inventory" : 5,
}
```

I would like a query which would rather return something like this:

```
[
    {
        name: "price",
        amount: 26
    },
    {
        name: "inventory",
        amount: 5
    }
]
```

EDIT:
How would I write this in Java with Spring Data? I can group and sum but don't know how to project it?

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
                group("$id")
                        .sum("price").as("price")
                        .sum("inventory").as("inventory")
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/). It allows us to define which fields will be returned, as well as their format.

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{ 
    $group: { 
        _id: null,
        price: {
            $sum: "$price"
        },
        inventory: {
            $sum: "$inventory"
        }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0 //removes _id from result
        something: [
            {name: "price", amount: "$price"},
            {name: "inventory", amount: "$inventory"}
        ]    
    }
}])
```

That will give you:

```
{
    "something" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "price",
            "amount" : 26
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "inventory",
            "amount" : 5
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to convert this to a Spring query? Updated my post

Comment: Sorry, man. Unfortunately, I don't have any experience on Spring.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "data": {
      "$map": {
        "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
        "in": { "name": "$$this.k", "amount": "$$this.v" }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" }},
  { "$match": { "amount": { "$ne": null }}
  }
])
```